# Do the Portal Super User and Portal Super Reader accounts configured for accessing the Object Cache need to be Managed Accounts?

Tags: 2010, managed-account, object-cache

The TechNet article [Configure object cache user accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx) doesn't say anything about it.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create normal user accounts for the object cache accounts. They don't need to be service accounts, according to [Mirjam van Olst](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/10/06/resolving-the-super-user-account-utilized-by-the-cache-is.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's not required that they are managed accounts, however, if your service account passwords expire you might as well register it for password changes.